# Suppose that $m \ge 0$ show that $49 \mid 5\cdot3^{4m + 2} + 53\cdot2^{5m}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I've re-written the equation in a few different ways hoping for a few different approaches:

$$49y = 5 \cdot 3^{4m + 2} + 53 \cdot 2^{5m} $$

I think the first equation has more potential, since it looks like I should be able to just solve for $m$, or get to a point where I can say that any positive $m$ will work, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to proceed to solve for $m$.

or

$5\cdot3^{4m + 2} + 53 \cdot 2^{5m} \equiv 0 \mod 49$
I'm not fabulous at congruence equations, but I was thinking I could reduce this down to something more manageable to solve the problem, but none of my congruence equation tricks really help.

Anyways I'm at a loss as to where to proceed, if you all have any tips on ways to proceed, that'd be great :D

Comment: You can write $5\cdot3$ or $5\times3$.  The notation $5*3$ is a workaround for use when you're restricted to the characters on the keyboard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ah, thanks for the help! I'm new and still learning latex : ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
5\cdot 3^{4(m + 1) + 2} + 53 \cdot 2^{5(m + 1)} &= 5 \cdot 3^{4m + 2} \cdot 3^4 + 53 \cdot 2^{5m} \cdot 2^5 \\
&= 81 \cdot \Big(5\cdot 3^{4m + 2}\Big) + 32 \cdot \Big(53 \cdot 2^{5m}\Big) \\
&= (49 + 32) \cdot\Big(5\cdot 3^{4m + 2}\Big) + 32 \cdot \Big(53 \cdot 2^m\Big) \\
&= 49 \cdot \Big(5 \cdot 3^{4m + 2}\Big) + 32 \cdot\Big(5 \cdot 3^{4m + 2} + 53 \cdot 2^m\Big)
\end{align*}

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Wow, thanks. Out of curiosity, how how did you know to do these steps? 

It seems like adding 1 to m would help to see the change that "m" causes, which is good.

After that, it looks like just playing around with algebra?

Just so that I have ideas of future problem solving techniques.

Comment: Induction is the first thing that came to mind, and I knew that factors of $49$ needed to come from somewhere. I was looking for common terms involving the previous expression, and a $49$ dropped out nicely from there.

Comment: @Katlyn You tagged it "congruences", which may imply that it was an exercise to help gain intuition on congruences. If so, the above is not the way to go, since such inductive proofs greatly obfuscate the arithmetical essence of the matter. Instead, I highly recommend that you study the answers using congruences, and take note of how much simpler such proofs are vs. induction.

Answer (score 4):

Work modulo $49$. Note that the first term is $45\cdot 81^m$, which is congruent to $45\cdot 32^m$.

The second term is congruent, indeed equal, to $53\cdot 32^m$.

Altogether, $98\cdot 32^m$. Finished!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 49\!:\ \color{#c00}{3^4} \equiv\, \color{#c00}{2^5}$

$\!\begin{eqnarray}{\rm Therefore} &&5\cdot 3^2\cdot \color{#c00}3^{\large \color{#c00}4m} + 53\cdot 2^{\large 5m}\\
\equiv &&\ \ \ \ 45\,\cdot \color{#c00}2^{\large \color{#c00}5m} +\  4\cdot 2^{\large5m}\\
\equiv && \ \ \ \ 49\cdot 2^{\large 5m}\,\equiv\ 0
\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
5\times 3^{4m + 2} + 53\times 2^{5m} = (49 -4)81^m + (49 + 4)32^m = 49\times(81^m + 32^m) - 4\times (81^m - 32^m)
$$
But, 
$$
81^m - 32^m = (49 + 32)^m - 32^m = \sum_{k=1}^{m - 1}{m \choose k}32^k 49^{m-k} = 49N
$$
Thus, $5\times 3^{4m + 2} + 53\times 2^{5m} = 49\times(81^m + 32^m) - 49N = 49M$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that 
\begin{align*}
2^{5} & \equiv 32 \pmod{49}\\
2^{5m} & \equiv 32^m \pmod{49}\\
53 \cdot 2^{5m} & \equiv 53 \cdot 32^m  \equiv 4 \cdot 32^m \pmod{49}
\end{align*}
Likewise 
\begin{align*}
3^{4} & \equiv 81 \equiv 32 \pmod{49}\\
3^{4m} & \equiv 32^m \pmod{49}\\
3^{4m+2} & \equiv 32^m \cdot 9 \pmod{49}\\
5 \cdot 3^{4m+2} & \equiv 32^m \cdot 45  \equiv 32^m \cdot (-4) \pmod{49}\\
\end{align*}
Now add the last two congruences of both systems to get
 $$53 \cdot 2^{5m}  +  5 \cdot 3^{4m+2} \equiv 4 \cdot 32^m + 32^m \cdot (-4) \equiv 0\pmod{49}$$

Answer (score 0):

We will prove by induction on $m \geq 0$ that:

> There is some $y \in \mathbb Z$ such that $49y = 5 \cdot 3^{4m + 2} + 53 \cdot 2^{5m}$.

**Base Case:** This holds for $m = 0$, since we can take $y = 2$.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that the claim holds for $m' = m - 1$, where $m \geq 1$.

It remains to show that the claim holds for $m' = m$. Now by the induction hypothesis, we know that there is some $z \in \mathbb Z$ such that:
$$
49z = 5 \cdot 3^{4m - 2} + 53 \cdot 2^{5m - 5} \tag{1}
$$

But then observe that:
\begin{align*}
5 \cdot 3^{4m + 2} + 53 \cdot 2^{5m}
&= (3^4)(5 \cdot 3^{4m - 2}) + 53 \cdot 2^{5m} \\
&= (3^4)(49z - 53 \cdot 2^{5m - 5}) + 53 \cdot 2^{5m}  &\text{by }(1)\\
&= 49(81z) - 53 \cdot 2^{5m - 5} \cdot 81 + 53 \cdot 2^{5m - 5} \cdot 2^5 \\
&= 49(81z) - 53 \cdot 2^{5m - 5}(81 - 32) \\
&= 49(81z) - 53 \cdot 2^{5m - 5}(49) \\
&= 49\underbrace{(81z - 53 \cdot 2^{5m - 5})}_{\in ~ \mathbb Z} \\
\end{align*}
So we can take $y = 81z - 53 \cdot 2^{5m - 5}$, as desired.$~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Since $49 \mid (5*3^{4m+2} + 53*2^{5m})$, only a few manipulations are needed,

$$49 \mid (5*3^2*3^{4m} + 53*2^{5m})$$
$$49 \mid 45*3^{4m} + 53*2^{5m}$$

You can stop here, since if you add $45$ and $53$, we get $98 = 49*2$. You can use the properties of mode $a_1 \equiv b_1 (\bmod c) + a_2 \equiv b_2(\bmod c) = a_1 + a_2 \equiv b_1 + b_2 (\bmod c)$, hence

$$45*3^{4m}  53*2^{5m}\equiv 0(\bmod 49)$$

Finishing the proof.